# Problemas de conexão Wifi e para instalar git no ubuntu 16.04

Tags: git, ubuntu

Eu sou uma nova usuaria do ubuntu 16.04 (comecei ontem!!). O meu PC ta em dual-boot com o Windows 10. Eu tenho dois problemas e ja estou meio desesperada...

1) O WiFi nao funciona (eu digito a senha e nada acontece). No windows e no telefone tudo funciona perfeitamente.

2) Eu preciso instalar o git para um curso, mas nao esta dando certo... eu faço **sudo apt-get install git** e aparece muitos **Erro temporario de resolução "fr.archive.ubuntu.com"**. Eu ja tentei fazer upgrades, mas nada... as mesmas mensagens de erro.

Alguém poderia, por gentileza, me ajudar a resolver estes problemas?

Obrigada!!!! :)

Ps. Desculpa a falta de acentos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o Wifi, tente conectar primeiro via cabo de rede, ver se funciona. É comum do linux não vir com alguns drivers de placa de wifi e placa de vídeo, por serem proprietários. Vá em configuração, depois em "drivers adicionais" e instale os drivers opcionais, mas para isso é necessário estar conectado a internet.

Para o apt-get install, primeiro, também é preciso ter acesso a internet para instalar os pacotes adicionais (é possível também via CD, mas é um processo mais complicado). Com acesso a internet, entre em configurações e em repositórios, selecione o repositório mais rápido (normalmente são os brasileiros, devido a menor distância).

Comment: Deu certo!!!!! Nossa, muito obrigada!! Me conectei com com um cabo e deu certinho!! Agora so falta configurar o wifi (to penando porque meu ubuntu nao ta em português.

Comment: Super obrigada mesmo!!

Comment: É possível alterar o idioma em System, Administration, Language Support